# VB.NET Copying Excel Range

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

I have used the code below to copy an excel range.

`oSheetDestination.Range("A1:A10").Value = oSheetSource.Range("A1:A10").Value`

But I would like to copy the range based on the cell number location using something like this:

```
oSheetDestination.Range("1,1:1,10").Value = oSheetSource.Range("1,1:1,10").Value
```

Any ideas how I can do that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the `Cells` property.  From there, your best bet is to do a `resize`

```
oSheetDestination.Cells(1,1).resize(1,10).Value = _
     oSheetSource.Cells(1,1).resize(1,10).Value
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
Friend Shared Sub TestRangeCells(myworksheet As Worksheet)
Dim myrange As Range = myworksheet.Range(worksheet.Cells(1, 1), myworksheet.Cells(5, 10))
MessageBox.Show(myrange.Address)
End Sub
```

Comment: While this may answer the question it’s always a good idea to put some text in your answer to explain what you're doing. Read [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I was in big hurry, if he don't get the clue, I will give them a full example .. But first I think is personal effort to try and understand ..